# Angular2: Get selected option in select component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using angular 2.0.0-rc.4.

I have a form (parent component), and I have in it some drop-down lists from other components, each dropdown has `ts` and `html template` else where, each one get its data from its component. When submitting the form I need the selected value of each one. How can I access it from the parent ?

-Parent Form HTML:

```
<form class="" (submit)="submitNewModel($event, label.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="label" class="control-label"> Label </label>
      <input type="text" name="label" #label class="form-control" placeholder="Model's label">
    </div>
    <styles-dropdown></styles-dropdown>
    <colors-dropdown></colors-dropdown>
    <modes-dropdown></modes-dropdown>
    <shapes-dropdown></shapes-dropdown>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Create new model</button>
</form>
```

-Parent `ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

...

@Component({
  selector: 'models',
  templateUrl: 'app/models/models.component.html',
  directives: [
    StylesDropDownComponent,
    ...
  ]
})
export class ModelsComponent {

  constructor(){
  }

  submitNewModel(event, label) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Value label', label);
    console.log(event);
    //How do I get selected values here ?
  }
}
```

-Drop down component HTML:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="styles" class="control-label"> Style </label>
    <select name="style-select" id="styles" class="form-control select2">
      <option value="">Select style</option>
      <option *ngFor="let style of styles" value="{{style.id}}">{{ style.label }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

-Drop down `ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ClientHttp } from '../../common/cigma-http';
import { StylesComponent } from '../styles.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'styles-dropdown',
  templateUrl: 'app/styles/styles-dropdown/styles.dropdown.component.html',
})
export class StylesDropDownComponent extends StylesComponent  {
  constructor(protected cigmaHttp: CigmaHttp) {
    super(cigmaHttp)
  }
}
```

All other dropdown component have the same structure as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Use evenEmitter to pass the value from parent to child component

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around and reading some useful topics:

To passe data from parent to nested component, we need to use `@Input` decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: 'child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {  
  @Input() title:string;
}
```

Now we can pass data to that property from the parent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: 'parent.component.html',
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {  
  childTitle:string = 'Information passed to child';
}
```

And of course:

```
/* parent.component.html */
<div>  
  <h1>Parent component</h1>
  <child[title]='childTitle'></child>
</div>
```

Without the `@input` decorator the child component wont know about the passed data from the parent.

---

And to pass data from Child to Parent we need to use eventEmitter.
You can [read more here](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/).